# How to let npm use sass which comes from local libsass-dev(installed by apt) instead of downloading its own package?

Tags: npm, sass

I have a `libsass-dev` on my system. But npm will download its own one, which is annoying. How to let npm makes use of `libsass-dev`?

Comment: `npm` download everything that is there in `package.json` and its dependency, so it really doesn't matter if you had it from apt, it will be downloaded into your project locally

Comment: @TarunLalwani Hi, there. I found `package.json` in `kibana/node_modules/node-sass`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/N3j2x7npfw/ and `package.json` under `kibana`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vpdb7sFTDx/ But I still cannot figure out how to tell this package.json to use libsass from apt

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the absolute path to your module, assuming is outside the `node_modules` folder.

You can try first the `require.resolve('/path/to/my/Module')` and if it finds it will return the path to the module, then do the `require` function.

Or You can create your own folder inside `node_modules` and require the full folder, something like `require('./relativeOrAbsPath/To/My/node_modules/myModule')`. The default file is `index.js` or You can mention in the `package.json` file using the `main` property to specify another file name.

Also you can update your *modules path* using this *npm module* https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path but this looks first on your *node_modules* folder. However on prior version 1.x is starting for the bottom of the `module.paths` list.